# Group by and display result for current month

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table as below

```
Reading (ReadingNo Int, Readdate Date, ReaderID Int)
```

I need to display a result of no.of reading read by each reader during the current month.

I tried with the below:

```
Select Count(*), to_char(Trunc(ReadDate,'mm'),'Month') Month
From Reading
Group By trunc (ReadDate,'mm');
```

Result = Number of reading done each month and

```
Select COUNT(*), ReaderID
From Reading
Group By ReaderID;
```

Result = Number of reading done by reader

However I need query that can nest this 2 statement to provide me with a result of the number of reading done by each reader during the current month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be as simple as:

```
Select Count(*), ReaderID, to_char(Trunc(ReadDate,'mm'),'Month') Month
From Reading
Group By  ReaderID, trunc (ReadDate,'mm');
```

Result = Number of reading done each month by Reader

or if you want a filter for an specific reader and just the current month you could use

```
Select Count(*)
From Reading
Where ReaderID = READER's CODE
AND Trunc(ReadDate,'mm') = Trunc(Sysdate,'mm')
```

Result = Number of reading done this month by ONE Reader